# Javascript not selecting after focusing on new element

Tags: javascript

I am working on an excel sheet like grading book that allows the user to navigate using the arrow keys. I have a couple of questions:

1. Why is the text inside of the input not being selected? My intended result is that when the user hits the arrow key to navigate through the gradebook, after the new cell is selected, the current value of that input should be "selected" so the user can easily override existing values. Why does `transport.select();` not work to do this?
2. How can I bring the new "active element" on to the screen if the element is hidden by the scrollbar? This is not visible with the current example, but if you have 100 rows and 100 columns then you would see what I mean.
3. Is there a better way to approach this problem than the way I have right now? Click on any input cell, and then use your arrow keys. The code (mostly) works as intended, but I'm open to suggestions on improving or modifying.

```js
document.onkeydown = function(key) {
  tagName = document.activeElement.tagName;
  row = parseInt(document.activeElement.dataset.row);
  column = parseInt(document.activeElement.dataset.column);
  if (tagName == 'INPUT') {
    if (key.keyCode == 37 || key.keyCode == 38 || key.keyCode == 39 || key.keyCode == 40) {
      if (key.keyCode == 37) {column = column - 1;}
      if (key.keyCode == 38) {row = row - 1;}
      if (key.keyCode == 39) {column = column + 1;}
      if (key.keyCode == 40) {row = row + 1;}
      transport = document.querySelectorAll("[data-row='" + row + "'][data-column='" + column + "']")[0];
      transport.focus();
      transport.select();
    }
  }
};
```

```css
   body {
     margin: 0;
     position: absolute;
     top: 105px; left: 0px;
     width: 100%;
     height: calc(100vh - 105px);
     background-color: #FCFCFC;
     display: grid;
     grid-template-rows: 1fr;
     grid-template-areas:
       "master"}

   .master {
     grid-area: master;
     overflow-x: scroll;}

   table {border-collapse: collapse}

   th, td {
     background-color: white;
     max-width: 110px;
     border: 1px solid lightgray;}

   th {overflow: hidden;}

  thead{
    top: 0;
    position: sticky;
    z-index: 1;}

  tr td:nth-child(1),
  tr th:nth-child(1){
    position: sticky;
    left: 0;}

   thead th.navigator { /* Top left cell with navigation controls */
     padding: 10px;
     z-index: 3;}

   tr td:first-child, tr td:nth-child(2) { /* First two columns of each row */
     white-space: nowrap;
     max-width: fit-content !important;}

   td input {
     border: none;
     outline: none;
     text-align: center;
     max-width: 80%;
     font-size: 18px;
     padding: 6px 0px;
     cursor: cell;}

   th select {
     outline: none;
     -webkit-appearance: none;
     padding: 8px 12px;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     border-radius: 8px;
     width: 100%;
     border: 1px solid lightgray}

  tr:focus-within td:not(.gray) {background-color: #E9DCF9}
  tr:focus-within td:not(.gray) input {background-color: #E9DCF9}

  .due {
    font-size: 11px;
    color: darkgray;}

   .assign {padding: 20px}
   .assign span {
     cursor: pointer;
     font-size: 15px;
     overflow: hidden;
     color: #581F98}

   .avg {padding: 10px}

   .studentInfo {
     display: flex;
     align-items: center;
     margin: 10px 12px 10px 6px;}

   .studentInfo img {
     width: 25px;
     margin-right: 10px;
     clip-path: circle();}

   .red {background-color: red;}
   .gray, .gray input {background-color: #F2F2F2;}

  .score {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;}
```

```html
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th class='navigator' colspan='2' rowspan='4'>
                <form method='GET'>
                  <select name='subID' onchange='this.form.submit()'>
                    <option value='1' >Reading</option>
                    <option value='2' >Social Studies</option>
                  </select>
                  <select name='week' onchange='this.form.submit()' disabled>
                    <option value='all'>Entire Quarter</option>
                  </select>
                </form>
              </th>
              <tr>
                <th class='due'><span title='Monday'>10/11</span> to <span title='Wednesday'>10/13</span></th>
                <th class='due'><span title='Wednesday'>10/20</span> to <span title='Friday'>10/22</span></th>
                <th class='due'><span title='Monday'>10/18</span> to <span title='Friday'>10/22</span></th>
                <th class='due'><span title='Wednesday'>10/20</span> to <span title='Friday'>10/22</span></th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th class='assign'>
                  <span title='Assignment ID: 130' onclick='assignInfo("130");'> Quiz</span>
                </th>
                <th class='assign'>
                  <span title='Assignment ID: 146' onclick='assignInfo("146");'> Homework</span>
                </th>
                <th class='assign'>
                  <span title='Assignment ID: 145' onclick='assignInfo("145");'> Test</span>
                </th>
                <th class='assign'>
                  <span title='Assignment ID: 147' onclick='assignInfo("147");'>✏️ Project</span>
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th class='avg gray'><span title='9.111/10'>91%</span></th>
              <th class='avg gray'><span title='8.672/10'>87%</span></th>
              <th class='avg gray'><span title='4.348/5'>87%</span></th>
              <th class='avg gray'><span title='8.007/10'>80%</span></th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div class='studentInfo'>
                <span title='Student ID: 11'><img src='../../resources/pics/students/11.jpg'></span>
                <span>John Doe</span>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td class='avg gray'>
              <span data-studentAvg='11' title='97.5/110'>89%</span>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class='score'>
                <input type='text' data-assID='130' data-usid='11' data-workID='7280' data-row='0' data-column='0' data-curScore='10' value='10'>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class='score'>
                <input type='text' data-assID='131' data-usid='11' data-workID='7282' data-row='0' data-column='1' data-curScore='9' value='9'>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class='score'>
                <input type='text' data-assID='132' data-usid='11' data-workID='7340' data-row='0' data-column='2' data-curScore='10' value='10'>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class='score'>
                <input type='text' data-assID='130' data-usid='11' data-workID='7280' data-row='0' data-column='3' data-curScore='10' value='10'>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div class='studentInfo'>
                <span title='Student ID: 12'><img src='../../resources/pics/students/12.jpg'></span>
                <span>Jane Doe</span>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td class='avg gray'>
              <span data-studentAvg='12' title='97.5/110'>69%</span>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class='score'>
                <input type='text' data-assID='130' data-usid='12' data-workID='7250' data-row='1' data-column='0' data-curScore='6' value='6'>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class='score'>
                <input type='text' data-assID='131' data-usid='12' data-workID='7211' data-row='1' data-column='1' data-curScore='9' value='9'>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class='score'>
                <input type='text' data-assID='132' data-usid='12' data-workID='7110' data-row='1' data-column='2' data-curScore='4' value='4'>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class='score'>
                <input type='text' data-assID='130' data-usid='12' data-workID='7233' data-row='1' data-column='3' data-curScore='10' value='10'>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div class='studentInfo'>
                <span title='Student ID: 13'><img src='../../resources/pics/students/13.jpg'></span>
                <span>Sally Martin</span>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td class='avg gray'>
              <span data-studentAvg='13' title='97.5/110'>100%</span>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class='score'>
                <input type='text' data-assID='130' data-usid='13' data-workID='6250' data-row='2' data-column='0' data-curScore='10' value='10'>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class='score'>
                <input type='text' data-assID='131' data-usid='13' data-workID='6211' data-row='2' data-column='1' data-curScore='10' value='10'>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class='score'>
                <input type='text' data-assID='132' data-usid='13' data-workID='7610' data-row='2' data-column='2' data-curScore='10' value='10'>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class='score'>
                <input type='text' data-assID='130' data-usid='13' data-workID='7933' data-row='2' data-column='3' data-curScore='10' value='10'>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: FYI, if you just want the first element matching a selector, use `querySelector()` rather than `querySelectorAll(...)[0]`

Comment: You should check if the selector finds anything before calling `.focus()` and `.select()`.

Comment: #2 you can use `.scrollT()` to scroll to the element, which will bring it onto the screen.

Comment: @Barmar I tried using ```window.scrollTo(transport.scrollTop);``` without any success.

Comment: `console.log(row, column);` Is it actually finding an active element? Is it actually finding an element? `console.log(document.querySelector("[data-row='" + row + "'][data-column='" + column + "']"))`

Comment: `transport.scrollIntoView()`

Comment: @epascarello yes it actually finds the right element, because the navigation portion of the script works and this debug output actual info. However, the select is just not working.

Comment: @Barmar that doesn't work at all, I presume because when I ```scrollIntoView()``` I am actually scrolling behind the first two cells, which have a z-index above the rest of the cells, so the active cell ends up being hidden behind them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simple, you need to prevent the keypress

```
key.preventDefault();
```

You really should name that variable event or evt or e since it is an event, not a key.

```js
document.onkeydown = function(key) {
  tagName = document.activeElement.tagName;
  row = parseInt(document.activeElement.dataset.row);
  column = parseInt(document.activeElement.dataset.column);
  if (tagName == 'INPUT') {
    if (key.keyCode == 37 || key.keyCode == 38 || key.keyCode == 39 || key.keyCode == 40) {
      key.preventDefault();
      if (key.keyCode == 37) {column = column - 1;}
      if (key.keyCode == 38) {row = row - 1;}
      if (key.keyCode == 39) {column = column + 1;}
      if (key.keyCode == 40) {row = row + 1;}
      transport = document.querySelector("[data-row='" + row + "'][data-column='" + column + "']");
      if (transport) {
        transport.scrollIntoView();
        transport.focus();
        transport.select();
      }
    }
  }
};
```

```css
body {
     margin: 0;
     position: absolute;
     top: 105px; left: 0px;
     width: 100%;
     height: calc(100vh - 105px);
     background-color: #FCFCFC;
     display: grid;
     grid-template-rows: 1fr;
     grid-template-areas:
       "master"}

   .master {
     grid-area: master;
     overflow-x: scroll;}

   table {border-collapse: collapse}

   th, td {
     background-color: white;
     max-width: 110px;
     border: 1px solid lightgray;}

   th {overflow: hidden;}

  thead{
    top: 0;
    position: sticky;
    z-index: 1;}

  tr td:nth-child(1),
  tr th:nth-child(1){
    position: sticky;
    left: 0;}

   thead th.navigator { /* Top left cell with navigation controls */
     padding: 10px;
     z-index: 3;}

   tr td:first-child, tr td:nth-child(2) { /* First two columns of each row */
     white-space: nowrap;
     max-width: fit-content !important;}

   td input {
     border: none;
     outline: none;
     text-align: center;
     max-width: 80%;
     font-size: 18px;
     padding: 6px 0px;
     cursor: cell;}

   th select {
     outline: none;
     -webkit-appearance: none;
     padding: 8px 12px;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     border-radius: 8px;
     width: 100%;
     border: 1px solid lightgray}

  tr:focus-within td:not(.gray) {background-color: #E9DCF9}
  tr:focus-within td:not(.gray) input {background-color: #E9DCF9}

  .due {
    font-size: 11px;
    color: darkgray;}

   .assign {padding: 20px}
   .assign span {
     cursor: pointer;
     font-size: 15px;
     overflow: hidden;
     color: #581F98}

   .avg {padding: 10px}

   .studentInfo {
     display: flex;
     align-items: center;
     margin: 10px 12px 10px 6px;}

   .studentInfo img {
     width: 25px;
     margin-right: 10px;
     clip-path: circle();}

   .red {background-color: red;}
   .gray, .gray input {background-color: #F2F2F2;}

  .score {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;}
```

```html
<table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th class='navigator' colspan='2' rowspan='4'>
                <form method='GET'>
                  <select name='subID' onchange='this.form.submit()'>
                    <option value='1' >Reading</option>
                    <option value='2' >Social Studies</option>
                  </select>
                  <select name='week' onchange='this.form.submit()' disabled>
                    <option value='all'>Entire Quarter</option>
                  </select>
                </form>
              </th>
              <tr>
                <th class='due'><span title='Monday'>10/11</span> to <span title='Wednesday'>10/13</span></th>
                <th class='due'><span title='Wednesday'>10/20</span> to <span title='Friday'>10/22</span></th>
                <th class='due'><span title='Monday'>10/18</span> to <span title='Friday'>10/22</span></th>
                <th class='due'><span title='Wednesday'>10/20</span> to <span title='Friday'>10/22</span></th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th class='assign'>
                  <span title='Assignment ID: 130' onclick='assignInfo("130");'> Quiz</span>
                </th>
                <th class='assign'>
                  <span title='Assignment ID: 146' onclick='assignInfo("146");'> Homework</span>
                </th>
                <th class='assign'>
                  <span title='Assignment ID: 145' onclick='assignInfo("145");'> Test</span>
                </th>
                <th class='assign'>
                  <span title='Assignment ID: 147' onclick='assignInfo("147");'>✏️ Project</span>
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th class='avg gray'><span title='9.111/10'>91%</span></th>
              <th class='avg gray'><span title='8.672/10'>87%</span></th>
              <th class='avg gray'><span title='4.348/5'>87%</span></th>
              <th class='avg gray'><span title='8.007/10'>80%</span></th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div class='studentInfo'>
                <span title='Student ID: 11'><img src='../../resources/pics/students/11.jpg'></span>
                <span>John Doe</span>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td class='avg gray'>
              <span data-studentAvg='11' title='97.5/110'>89%</span>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class='score'>
                <input type='text' data-assID='130' data-usid='11' data-workID='7280' data-row='0' data-column='0' data-curScore='10' value='10'>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class='score'>
                <input type='text' data-assID='131' data-usid='11' data-workID='7282' data-row='0' data-column='1' data-curScore='9' value='9'>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class='score'>
                <input type='text' data-assID='132' data-usid='11' data-workID='7340' data-row='0' data-column='2' data-curScore='10' value='10'>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class='score'>
                <input type='text' data-assID='130' data-usid='11' data-workID='7280' data-row='0' data-column='3' data-curScore='10' value='10'>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div class='studentInfo'>
                <span title='Student ID: 12'><img src='../../resources/pics/students/12.jpg'></span>
                <span>Jane Doe</span>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td class='avg gray'>
              <span data-studentAvg='12' title='97.5/110'>69%</span>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class='score'>
                <input type='text' data-assID='130' data-usid='12' data-workID='7250' data-row='1' data-column='0' data-curScore='6' value='6'>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class='score'>
                <input type='text' data-assID='131' data-usid='12' data-workID='7211' data-row='1' data-column='1' data-curScore='9' value='9'>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class='score'>
                <input type='text' data-assID='132' data-usid='12' data-workID='7110' data-row='1' data-column='2' data-curScore='4' value='4'>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class='score'>
                <input type='text' data-assID='130' data-usid='12' data-workID='7233' data-row='1' data-column='3' data-curScore='10' value='10'>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div class='studentInfo'>
                <span title='Student ID: 13'><img src='../../resources/pics/students/13.jpg'></span>
                <span>Sally Martin</span>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td class='avg gray'>
              <span data-studentAvg='13' title='97.5/110'>100%</span>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class='score'>
                <input type='text' data-assID='130' data-usid='13' data-workID='6250' data-row='2' data-column='0' data-curScore='10' value='10'>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class='score'>
                <input type='text' data-assID='131' data-usid='13' data-workID='6211' data-row='2' data-column='1' data-curScore='10' value='10'>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class='score'>
                <input type='text' data-assID='132' data-usid='13' data-workID='7610' data-row='2' data-column='2' data-curScore='10' value='10'>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class='score'>
                <input type='text' data-assID='130' data-usid='13' data-workID='7933' data-row='2' data-column='3' data-curScore='10' value='10'>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: Thank you! This helps a lot. However, from the UX side, ```transport.scrollIntoView();``` is not working as intended. Is this because the first row is "frozen" with a z-index above the other rows?

Comment: Also, try typing a new value after keypress while the new cell is highlighted - you will see that the user is unable to "override" existing scores, almost as if the input is disabled. They should be able to hit the down arrow key, type a score, and that new score override the old score.

Comment: The key.preventDefault(); should be in the if.... whoops